# How to compute the coordinates of an enlarged shape in R?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

Note: I am working in R but my question is more of a logical thinking rather than an R specific question.

I am building a shiny app where users draw a shape on a 20-by-20 grid like the black shape shown in the picture below. The shape is presented in the server function by a table like the one shown below as well. In the table, every side of the shape is represented by a row indicating the points where the side starts and ends, namely, (`x`,`y`) and (`xend`,`yend`).

How can I use this table to compute another one that corresponds to the red shape shown in the picture. I would like the new shape to encapsulate the user entered shape leaving a 1-point gap.

[image: example of the shape entered by the user and the desired shape to be computed]

You may use the following code to reproduce the table at your end.

```
structure(list(sideNo = 1:8, x = c(4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 15L, 
18L), y = c(3L, 7L, 16L, 19L, 3L, 16L, 7L, 3L), xend = c(18L, 
15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 8L, 15L, 18L), yend = c(3L, 7L, 16L, 19L, 
7L, 19L, 16L, 19L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I would initially think of `st_buffer` in `sf` to calculate this but it seems it does not do the square corners. I would avoid custom code since the shape of objects can become quite complex so buffer functions might be an easy way to go.
One solution might be to move a shape 4 times (up down left right) and union those four shapes? e.g.:

Comment: something likes this: `p<-st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0)))); a<-list(p+c(1,1),p-c(0,1), p+c(-1,1), p, p+c(-1,0), p+c(1,0),p+c(1,-1),p+c(0,-1), p+c(-1,-1), p+c(0,1)); plot(Reduce(st_union,a))`